# Transitive geodesics on closed surfaces of genus greater than one

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

A well-known result of Hedlund and Morse states that if a Riemannian metric on a closed surface of genus $g > 1$ has no conjugate points, then it carries transitive geodesics (i.e., geodesics whose velocity vectors are dense in the unit tangent bundle).

*Are there Riemannian metrics on closed surfaces of genus $g > 1$ that do not carry  a transitive geodesic and if so what is the weakest condition known under which the existence of transitive geodesics has been proved?*

**Addendum.** As Misha remarks in his answer, it is easy to construct to metrics on any closed surface that do not carry a transitive geodesic. However,  the metrics I'm interested in have the additional property that *the lifted metric on the universal cover has no trapped geodesics.* In other words, no geodesic stays forever in a compact subset of the open unit disc.

Comment: Take a round sphere, drill a hole in it from the north pole to the south pole. This is a torus without transitive geodesics and with no trapped geodesics. You can attach some handles on periphery if you'd like to.

Comment: Thanks Andrey !! Could you please write this as an answer ?

Comment: This is not much different from katz's answer, so I'd rather not. Here is a possible continuation: assume additionally that the set of non-periodic geodesics is dense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is both: answer on the new version of the question and comment on comment of Andrey Gogolev, who asked whether  one can make the question more complicated  assuming 
 additionally that the set of non-periodic geodesics is dense.

Hier is an example that answers both:   it  is not much different from the answer of Andrey from his comment (and also from katz's answer).

Take a torus with periodic coordinates $x,y$ and 
 a liouville metric $(X(x) -Y(y)) (dx^2 + dy^2)$ on it (whose geodesic flow is integrable). Make two small holes on the torus  near the points where $X$ has minimum and $Y$ has maximum and connect by a neck. For generic $X$ and $Y$  and generic neck the set of nonperiodic geodesic  is dence but still it has a 'regular' region  in the tangent space where no geodesic passing through at least one point of neck can   come.  The closure of a typical geodesic from  the regular region is a torus in the tangent space which is projected to an annulus on the torus and after passing to the universal cover this annulus becomes an infinite unboundend  band.

One more remark is that 
by KAM theory, this examples survives  if you slightly perturbe the metric.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. It does seems then that the Morse-Hedlund theorem is as good as it gets. By the way that theorem has now been extended to Finsler metrics by Gomes and Ruggiero (for reversible metrics it is just the same techniques, but the extension is not trivial for non-reversible metrics).

Comment: What is  Morse-Hedlund theorem and why one can not make it better?

Comment: @Matveev: ?? that's the question posted.

Comment: Of course. Sorry. As always I skipped   the introduction and went to the question immediately. By the way, Victor Bangert claimed that he could proved the existence of a finsler metric on a  closed surface of genus >1 whose geodesic flow is integrable -- he did not publish the proof as far as I know though

Comment: I think Gabriel Paternain proved that a real analytic Finsler metric on a surface of genus g > 1 cannot be integrable. That makes me quite curious about this example of Bangert !!

Comment: This is a much better example because it is robust. In fact, if you put negative curvature on the necks you can probably say a something about the "chaotic part". This is a difficult subject in dynamics: coexistence of KAM and hyperbolic dynamics. Your example is geometric and I wonder if it was discussed in the literature. I know several references (on coexistence), but none talks about coexistence for the geodesic flow.

Comment: to @alvarezpaiva Everybody wants to see this example of Bangert which is actually not an explicit example but a proof of the existence. The example is not real anylytic of course and is obtained as a limit of a sequence of finsler metrics

Comment: to @Andrey Gogolev As far as I know the example itself was not discussed in the literature but the idea (which you and Misha Katz also  explained in your answers) is definitely not new and the additional information came from study of Liouville metrics on the torus which is not a big deal and can be obtained by hands

Comment: @VladimirSMatveev: but is this example smooth and quadratically convex? There are some really odd (and interesting) things that can happen (Zoll tori, for example) if you depart a bit from the orthodox definition of a Finsler metric.

Comment: You better ask Victor about it -- he explained me the idea of the proof but I did not check the whole proof/construction. As far I remember the metric is smooth and quadratically convex.

Answer (score 4):

A connected sum of a hyperbolic surface with the round sphere along a thin neck near the south pole will not be transitive in this sense, because any geodesic arriving from the thin neck will never reach vectors close to the tangent vectors of the equator, because any great circle near the equator stays away from the south pole. Related thread [Surfaces filled densely by a geodesic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127530/surfaces-filled-densely-by-a-geodesic)

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I was really thinking of metrics that do not contain trapped geodesics in their universal cover. I'll change the question to reflect this.