# Simply connected manifolds with dense geodesics on the tangent bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ergodic-theory, geodesics

A unit speed geodesic $\gamma:I\to M$ on a Riemannian manifold $M$ can be lifted to a curve $\sigma=(\gamma,\gamma')$ on $SM$, the unit sphere bundle (the unit tangent bundle) of $M$.
Let us say that the geodesic $\gamma$ is dense on the tangent bundle if the trace $\sigma(I)$ of $\sigma$ is dense on $SM$.
The existence of a dense geodesic in this sense can be regarded as a form of ergodicity (or mixing) of the geodesic flow.

Are there simply connected Riemannian manifolds for which a geodesic is dense on the tangent bundle?
Does the answer depend on dimension?

I know that such geodesics exist on all compact Anosov manifolds.
This includes negatively curved closed surfaces, but they have genus $\geq2$ and are not simply connected.

I failed to find an example or proof of non-existence.

Comment: I think Joseph O'Rourke already asked this some time ago and the answer was positive, such metrics exist on 2-spheres.

Comment: I am not sure but I also think there are examples on the sphere. I'd appreciate it if you could clarify what you exactly mean by "trace of $\sigma$" and the connection with ergodicity.

Comment: @vap, I clarified the question a bit.

Comment: @Misha, Joseph's question is related and useful, but it only studies embedded surfaces instead of all manifolds. Also, he only requires density on the base $M$, not on the sphere bundle $SM$. (For example, the flat torus has geodesics dense on the base, but none dense on $SM$.)

Comment: Link to my earlier question: [Surfaces filled densely by a geodesic](http://mathoverflow.net/q/127530/6094).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Burns and Donnay proved that every surface (including a sphere) admits a Riemannian metric that makes the geodesic flow ergodic with respect to Liouville measure, and hence topologically transitive (there is some $v\in SM$ whose orbit under the geodesic flow is dense in $SM$, in other words, the corresponding geodesic is dense in $SM$ in the sense you describe in the question):  see
["Embedded surfaces with ergodic geodesic flows", Internat. J. Bifur. Chaos Appl. Sci. Engrg. 7 (1997), no. 7, 1509–1527](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1486942).  The abstract to that paper reads as follows:

> Following ideas of Osserman, Ballmann and Katok, we construct smooth
>   surfaces with ergodic, and indeed Bernoulli, geodesic flow that are
>   isometrically embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. These surfaces can have
>   arbitrary genus and can be made analytic.

As Misha's comment points out, this is related to an [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127530/surfaces-filled-densely-by-a-geodesic) of Joseph O'Rourke, although that one seems to be about density on the surface, rather than in the unit tangent bundle.  [Misha's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/127552/5701) to that question references a 2004 paper by Donnay and Pugh that builds on the Burns-Donnay construction from the paper above.

Comment: Thanks! By a dense geodesic do you mean one that is dense on $SM$ or only on $M$? The second does not imply the first (example: flat torus). I think this is a sufficient answer for embedded surfaces, and I hope there are similar results on more general manifolds.

Comment: Right, I should have been more explicit - I mean the stronger property, density on $SM$.  I edited the answer to reflect this.